# How to unit test for windows app sdk application

Tags: .net, windows-app-sdk

I have made an app in windows app sdk, this app works and has quite a bit of code.

However recently we had a small unseen bug that caused a bit of an issue. To prevent this, we have decided to create unit tests that test from the inside instead of just doing outside testing(just run the app and act like you're the user).

The question is how do I unit test this application? I have followed this guide https://devblogs.microsoft.com/ifdef-windows/winui-desktop-unit-tests/
and it works fine. But if i want to continue and reference my project it crashes with a kernelbase.dll error.
So since that way is clearly not the way, what is the correct method to create unit tests for all my functions? How do I mock the data required for my flows? How do I simulate a chekbox being checked a field filled or a button pressed?

thank you for your time